# Protecting Cryptographic Keys with Biometric Authentication on Android

Tags: android, cryptography

The goal is to store a key inside an Android device which is protected by the fingerprint, faceprint, or passcode, depending on which are available.

The key should not be accessible in software without providing a valid fingerprint.

The key should not be stored outside of the device unless a valid fingerprint is provided.

The key should not be accessible outside of hardware, meaning that compromised software implementations should not be able to access the key.

This is similar to the iOS KeyChain.

The question is how this can be achieved. I have done extensive research, and most implementations simply return a boolean to indicate whether biometric authentication was successful.

Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [`authenticate(CryptoObject)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject.html) API? [Here's a demo app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/samples/BiometricDemos/src/main/java/com/example/android/biometric).

Comment: When I try to authenticate, a few errors happen. When I use `authenticate(PromptInfo)`, the UI shows up but `onAuthenticationSucceeded` passes an `AuthenticationResult` with a `null` CryptoObject (which is expected). When I pass in a CryptoObject (e.g. `authenticate(PromptInfo, CryptoObject)`,the application crashes with an error stating that the crypto primitive (my `Cipher`) must be initialized. However, when I call `Cipher.init()` on my Cipher with the PrivateKey stored in KeyStore, I get an error saying that the key cannot be initialized because the user is not authenticated.